# Can someone respond to a question by just saying "I´ll" instead of "I will"? Why or why not?

Tags: grammar, contractions, contraction-vs-full-form, esl

My friend keeps on responding to questions by just saying "I´ll". This doesn´t seem grammatically correct to me. However I would like to know what would be the proper use of that contraction.

Answer (score 0):

You have to say "I will" in this case.
This contraction can be used only in full sentences. Try to pronounce it on its own without completing the sentence, it'll make no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard anyone as a native speaker say this or write this. Consider a teacher asking a question: "Who will answer this question?" A student yells out, "I will!" Another one replies, "I'll answer it, Mr. Jones!"

The contraction of "I will" to "I'll" makes the rest of the sentence shorter. If the entire sentence is "I will," the contraction is unnecessary. That is why nobody (except perhaps to be funny) says, "I'll" as a full sentence.

Comment: I am not a native English speaker, so I really appreciate you taking the time to respond to my question. This helped.